# Why do I get the error lateinit property appContext has not been initialized?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have added the keyword `lateinit` before `var appContext: Context`, why do I still get the following error with Code A?

*lateinit property appContext has not been initialized*

BTW, the Code B is OK

**Code A**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class UIApp : Application() {

    lateinit var appContext: Context

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appContext = applicationContext
    }
    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class UIApp : Application() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var appContext: Context
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appContext = applicationContext
    }
```

Comment: Something is trying to read from that property before you've initialised it - the stacktrace should tell you where it's happening. Adding `lateinit` just allows you declare the property without giving it an initial value, promising the compiler you'll handle it in time - you still have to assign a value to it before it's read

Comment: It all depends on how you access it. You didn't show it, but I'm guessing that with Code A you are actually somewhere calling `UIApp().appContext` instead of the `UIApp.appContext` that you would do with Code B. This first way is wrong because you then create a new `UIApp` instance that is NOT the one that is actually running your app and it won't have called `onCreate`.